# c#: Can not receive UDP broadcast data on IPv6 and get remote address

Tags: c#, udp, ipv6

I have a client machine sending IPv4 and IPv6 broadcasts on port 47416 and I need to receive the data and get the remote IPv6 end point address. This code does not work (Yes, ipAddress[0] is definitely IPv6). No data is ever received (works fine for IPv4).

```
IPAddress[] ipAddress = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList;
IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress[0], 47416);
            
UdpClient listener = new UdpClient(ipEndPoint);

Console.WriteLine("Waiting for broadcast");

IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 47416);
byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);

Console.WriteLine($"Received broadcast from {RemoteIpEndPoint} :");
Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes));
```

I have tried this as well:

```
Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Raw, ProtocolType.Udp);
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, 47416);
EndPoint senderRemote = ep;
sock.Bind(ep);
byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
sock.ReceiveFrom(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref senderRemote);
string r = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
Console.WriteLine("packet received " + r + "-----" + ((IPEndPoint)senderRemote).Address);
```

which does actually receive the data but the remote address comes back as ::ffff:192.168.1.177:0. The port 0 seems very odd. This code also gets other broadcasts from routers etc which I don't want to see.

This is driving me slightly insane so any help welcome.

Comment: "_I have a client machine sending IPv4 and IPv6 broadcasts on port 47416_" No, you do not because there is no such thing as an IPv6 broadcast. IPv6 has eliminated broadcast because it interrupts every host on the LAN, and it is a  security risk. The modern way of doing things is to use multicast, and IPv6 makes heavy use of multicast.

Comment: The first solution isn't waiting for data.  It just reads the stream which may be empty.  You need to wait.  Second solution you are waiting to read to read 4096 bytes. The best way is to either send the byte count at beginning of message or terminate every message with an end character.

Comment: Thank you Ron! I was on the wrong path altogether and now have multicast working perfectly. Cheers.